# Renaming column in tidyeval in dplyr 1.0

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rlang, tidyeval

I wish to generate new columns based on receiving variables in tidy evaluation. For example,

```r
library(dplyr)

some_custom_measure <- function(.data, cola, colb) {
    .data %>% mutate("{{ cola }}_x_{{ colb }}" := {{ cola }} * {{ colb }})
}
iris %>% 
    some_custom_measure(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width) %>% 
    head()
```

The new column will be named `Sepal.Length_x_Sepal.Width`.

How do I manipulate the variables as string when forming new name **in the custom function**? I wish to accomplish something like `sepal_length_x_sepal_width`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `deparse(substitute(...))` to capture each variable name as a string and store it to a variable.

You can then process that variable however you like to manipulate the string. When you come to use it, put the variable inside single curly brackets in your column name specification.

```r
library(dplyr)

some_custom_measure <- function(.data, cola, colb) {

    cola_name <- tolower(gsub("\\.", "_", deparse(substitute(cola))))
    colb_name <- tolower(gsub("\\.", "_", deparse(substitute(colb))))

    .data %>% mutate("{cola_name}_x_{colb_name}" := {{ cola }} * {{ colb }})
}

iris %>% 
    some_custom_measure(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width) %>% 
    head()
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
#>   sepal_length_x_sepal_width
#> 1                      17.85
#> 2                      14.70
#> 3                      15.04
#> 4                      14.26
#> 5                      18.00
#> 6                      21.06
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, I figure out there is `as_name(enquo(...))` in `rlang`

Comment: I recommend using `rlang::as_label()` which, unlike `deparse()`, is guaranteed to return a length 1 string. The `rlang::as_name()` variant additionally checks that the input is a single name, whereas `as_label()` works with any expression.